# ruby irb does not function?

Tags: ruby, irb

I am not able to access ruby via irb in the console. What is the problem?

```
$ irb
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/json-1.8.1 (Errno::EACCES)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in `write_gem_make_out'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:132:in `build_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:171:in `rescue in build_extension'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:156:in `build_extension'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/locale.rb:150:in `block in search_file'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/locale.rb:158:in `block in each_localized_path'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/locale.rb:167:in `each_sublocale'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/locale.rb:157:in `each_localized_path'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/locale.rb:145:in `search_file'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/locale.rb:124:in `find'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/locale.rb:108:in `load'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/locale.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/init.rb:114:in `new'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/init.rb:114:in `init_config'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/init.rb:16:in `setup'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb.rb:380:in `start'
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You can see that the user you are trying to run irb with doesn't have permissions to json gem, which is loaded when irb is run. How did you install ruby on your machine?

Comment: Ruby came with the system that I am using (mac os maverick).

Comment: My suggestion will be to try installing rvm or rbenv. They are ruby version managers and will it make it easier to manage gems, and their permissions. Give them a try and if you get stuck post back. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just installed rbenv. I am still having the same issue. How can I do a clean install of ruby 2.0?

Comment: Ruby 2 comes with OS X Mavericks, mine works just fine so somehow yours got hosed. You could try using `/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility` to verify and/or repair disk permissions. You could also try a gem uninstall/reinstall of json-1.8.1, the offending gem, assuming you have admin privileges.

Comment: You haven't told us anything very useful. Append the output of `gem env` to your question by editing it, and adding that information. `gem env` is a good report of the health of your Ruby ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did find a solution to the problem. It was the Root/Superuser Access and all I had to do was sudo -s

Comment: @geographer answer below, and accept

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, somehow the JSON gem was either not avaialble or remvoed. I installed the json gem again, now ruby & irb will run now.

```
sudo gem install json
```